# Optionally load starters in spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

Assume I have multiple starters in my spring boot application: S1, S2, S3, etc.

Each starter might have its own auto configuration classes defined in spring.factories.

Now, I'd like to run some spring boot test (or spring test) that only lauch S1 and S2
(Because I know S1 and S2 are enough for my test, and launch other starters might slow down my test)

And I dont want to use something like:

@ContextConfiguration(classes = ... )

Because autoconfigrations in spring.factories are implementation details, and it's not good to let user list them all.

I'd like to see something like:

```
@EnableStarters({"aaa-starter", "bbb-starter"}) // aaa-starter could be the artifact name
public class MyTest
```

is it doable? like with some customized BootStrap or SmartContextLoader?

Or can I do something like @DataJpaTest did, use some special annotation to define which configurations needs to be loaded and let user to use, something like:

```
@OnlyLoadS1AndS2Test
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can load whatever you want.  The term "starter" pertains to "standard set of dependent jars"; not "what methods get executed when your app beings running".

Comment: A starter is nothing more then a collection of jars. If someone includes those jars independently it will still auto-configure, it not relies on the presence of a starter.